# plotting points along a straight line from a random start position

Tags: java

I am looking for some help with some game code i have inherited from a flight sim. The code below simulates bombs exploding on the ground, it works fine but i am trying to refine it.

At the moment it takes a random value for x and y as a start point and then adds another random value between -20 and 20 to this. It works ok, but doesn't simulate bombs dropping very well as the pattern does not lay along a straight line/

What i would like to achieve though is all x and y points after the first random values, to lay along a straight line, so that the effects called for all appear to lay in a line. It doesn't matter which way the line is orientated.

Thanks for any help

slipper

```
 public static class BombUnit extends CandCGeneric
{

    public boolean danger()
    {
        Point3d point3d = new Point3d();
        pos.getAbs(point3d);
        Vector3d vector3d = new Vector3d();
        Random random = new Random();
        Aircraft aircraft = War.GetNearestEnemyAircraft(this, 10000F, 9);
        if(counter > 10)
        {
            counter = 0;
            startpoint.set(point3d.x + (double)(random.nextInt(1000) - 500), point3d.y + (double)(random.nextInt(1000) - 500), point3d.z);
        }
        if(aircraft != null && (aircraft instanceof TypeBomber) && aircraft.getArmy() != myArmy)
        {
            World.MaxVisualDistance = 50000F;
            counter++;
            String s = "weapon.bomb_std";
            startpoint.x += random.nextInt(40) - 20;
            startpoint.y += random.nextInt(40) - 20;
            Explosions.generate(this, startpoint, 7F, 0, 30F, !Mission.isNet());
            startpoint.z = World.land().HQ(startpoint.x, startpoint.y);
            MsgExplosion.send(this, s, startpoint, getOwner(), 0.0F, 7F, 0, 30F);
            Engine.land();
            int i = Landscape.getPixelMapT(Engine.land().WORLD2PIXX(startpoint.x), Engine.land().WORLD2PIXY(startpoint.y));
            if(firecounter < 100 && i >= 16 && i < 20)
            {
                Eff3DActor.New(null, null, new Loc(startpoint.x, startpoint.y, startpoint.z + 5D, 0.0F, 90F, 0.0F), 1.0F, "Effects/Smokes/CityFire3.eff", 300F);
                firecounter++;
            }
            super.setTimer(15);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Point3d startpoint = new Point3d();
    private int counter;
    private int firecounter;


    public BombUnit()
    {
        counter = 11;
        firecounter = 0;
        Timer1 = Timer2 = 0.05F;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your startpoint is a StartPoint class with x,y,z coordinates as integers in it.

I hope I have understood your problem correctly. It looks like you either want to create a vertical explosion or a horizontal explosion. Since an explosion always occurs on ground, the z coordinate will be zero. Now you can vary one of x or y coordinate to give you a random explosion along a straight line. Whether you choose x or y could be fixed or could be randomized itself. A potential randomized solution below:

```
public boolean danger() {
  // stuff
  int orientation = Random.nextInt(2);
  if(aircraft != null && (aircraft instanceof TypeBomber) && aircraft.getArmy() != myArmy)
    {
      // stuff
      startPoint = randomizeStartPoint(orientation, startPoint);
      // stuff
    }
}

StartPoint randomizeStartPoint(int orientation, StartPoint startPoint) {
  if(orientation == 0) {
    startPoint.x += random.nextInt(40) - 20;
  }
  else {
    startPoint.y += random.nextInt(40) - 20;
  }
  return startPoint;
}
```

In response to the image you uploaded, it seems that the orientation of the explosion need not necessarily be horizontal or vertical. So the code I posted above gives a limited solution to your problem.

Since you want any random straight line, your problem boils down to two sub parts:
1. Generate a random straight line equation.
2. Generate random point along this line.

Now, a straight line equation in coordinate geometry is `y = mx + c` where `m` is the slope and `c` is the constant where the line crosses the y-axis. The problem with `c` is that it gives rise to irrational coordinates. I am assuming you are looking for integer coordinates only, since this will ensure that your points are accurately plotted. (You could do with rational fractions, but then a fraction like 1/3 will still result in loss of accuracy). The best way to get rid of this irrational problem is to get rid of `c`. So now your straight line always looks like `y = mx`. So for step one, you have to generate a random `m`.

Then for step 2, you can either generate a random `x` or random `y`. It doesn't matter which one, since either one will result in random coordinates.
Here is a possible code for the solution:

```
int generateRandomSlope() {
  return Random.nextInt(100); // arbitrarily chose 100.
}

int randomizeStartPoint(int m, StartPoint startPoint) { // takes the slope we generated earlier. without the slope, your points will never be on a straight line!
  startPoint.x += random.nextInt(40) - 20;
  startPoint.y += x * m; // because a line equation is y = mx
  return startPoint;
}

public boolean danger() {
  // stuff
  int m = generateRandomSlope(); // you may want to generate this elsewhere so that it doesn't change each time danger() is called.
  if(aircraft != null && (aircraft instanceof TypeBomber) && aircraft.getArmy() != myArmy)
    {
      // stuff
      startPoint = randomizeStartPoint(m, startPoint);
      // stuff
    }
}
```

Again, this is not a complete or the best solution.

Comment: ritrattThanks for your post

Comment: the first explosion should be random and the rest of the series should follow on a straight line (any direction) from the first. Is that what your code does?

Comment: posted an image in first post

Comment: Really grateful for you taking the time to answer. I am aware of the equation of a straight line but couldn't figure how to make subsequent points run from the one before, i will try your suggestion(s) over the weekend and get back to you. regards

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is a mess, but ignoring this and trying to focus on the relevant parts: You can generate a random position for the first point, and a random direction, and then walk along this direction in several steps.

(This still raises the question of whether the direction is *really* not important. Wouldn't it matter if only the first bomb was dropped in the "valid" area, and the remaining ones outside of the screen?)

However, the relevant code could roughly look like this:

```
class Bombs
{
    private final Random random = new Random(0);

    int getScreenSizeX() { ... }
    int getScreenSizeY() { ... }

    // Method to drop a single bomb at the given position
    void dropBombAt(double x, double y) { ... }


    void dropBombs(int numberOfBombs, double distanceBetweenBombs)
    {
        // Create a random position in the screen
        double currentX = random.nextDouble() * getScreenSizeX();
        double currentY = random.nextDouble() * getScreenSizeY();

        // Create a random step size
        double directionX = random.nextDouble();
        double directionY = random.nextDouble();
        double invLength = 1.0 / Math.hypot(directionX, directionY);
        double stepX = directionX * invLength * distanceBetweenBombs;
        double stepY = directionY * invLength * distanceBetweenBombs;

        // Drop the bombs              
        for (int i=0; i<numberOfBombs; i++)
        {
            dropBombAt(currentX, currentY);
            currentX += stepX;
            currentY += stepY;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, i inherited the code myself, and i'm also new to programming so not that experienced. I will try your suggestion over the weekend and report back. Greatly appreciate you taking the time to reply. regards